# When using Internet Explorer, why can't I access the selectedIndex of a <select> drop down menu embedded within an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, local-storage

I'm currently working on a (course application form) web page which uses a **JavaScript** function (`window.onload`)  to target a `<select>` drop-down menu *embedded on a separate web page* within an *iFrame*.

My function, which is called from the parent window, auto-populates the `selectedIndex` of the `<select>` menu by looping through the available drop-down options and cross-referencing these with a variable value which is captured through the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) method (on a different section of the website).

The parent (main web page) and child (iFrame) windows are both hosted on the same domain to ensure there are no cross-security related issues.

[image]

**The Background:**

*Step 1:*

The user accesses one of our unique [course information pages](http://www.agrifoodatp.ac.uk/aatp/courses/animals/meat-science-and-meat-quality.aspx).

*Step 2:*

After clicking on the green '**Sign Up Here**' button (right column), the `<h4>` semi-opaque banner value (i.e. the course title) is captured via the `localStorage` method:

```
//Capture the Course Title and add to local storage
var capturedTitle = document.getElementById("imageTopHeading").textContent || document.getElementById("imageTopHeading").innerText;
localStorage.setItem('storageName',capturedTitle);
```

*Step 3:*

With the 'Sign Up Here' button clicked, the user is navigated to the [Apply Form page](http://www.agrifoodatp.ac.uk/aatp/apply/index.aspx) containing our iFrame.

*Step 4:*

Our JavaScript function then:

- Retrieves the title value held in our `localStorage` and assigns this
  to a variable we can actually use (`desiredValue`).
- Targets the iFrame through it's unique
  ID (`applyForm`).
- Sets up a further variable which targets the `<select>` dropdown
  menu itself (`sdd`).
- Uses a for loop and goes through each menu
  option (course title) until it finds a match with our `desiredValue`.
- Accesses the iFrame a final time and fires two of the form's (`applyForm`)
  internal functions (`selectCourse();` and `validateNext();`) , which
  populates the details of the selected course on the screen below the
  drop-down and also brings the 'Next' button into play.

---

```
window.onload = function() {

   testAccess();

   var dropDownValue = localStorage.getItem("storageName");

   var iframe = document.getElementById('applyForm');

   var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

   console.log("InnerDoc = " + innerDoc);
   console.log("Course Title = " + dropDownValue);

   var desiredValue = dropDownValue;
   var sdd = innerDoc.getElementById("coursesDropdown");

   for (var i=0; i < sdd.options.length; i++) {
       if (sdd.options[i].text === desiredValue ) {
           sdd.selectedIndex = i;
           console.log("Counter = " + i);
           console.log("Drop Text = " + sdd.options[i].text);
           break;
          }
     }

 if (iframe.contentWindow) {

        iframe.contentWindow.selectCourse();
        iframe.contentWindow.validateNext();
  }
    else if (iframe.contentDocument) {
        iframe.contentDocument.selectCourse();
        iframe.contentDocument.validateNext();
    }
}

function canAccessIFrame(iframe) {
    var html = null;
    try { 
      // deal with older browsers
      var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      html = doc.body.innerHTML;
    } catch(err){
      // do nothing
}

return(html !== null);
}

function testAccess() {
var local = canAccessIFrame(document.getElementById("applyForm"));
console.log("Local iframe canAccess: " + local);
}
```

If you try out Steps 1-4 using browsers such as Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera or Safari this code works as intended.

---

**So... What's the Problem Then?**

Well.. Two (dreaded) words.. Internet Explorer. With your browser console open, try steps 1-4 using IE, including the more modern versions and the auto-population function fails to work properly.

I have integrated some `console.log` requests into the function and in IE I'm successfully getting the course title and Boolean notification that the iFrame is on the same domain as it's parent window, so it must be the for loop sequence which is causing the issue?

Something tells me that `sdd.selectedIndex = i;` could be the culprit? Isn't there a `.value` option too?

Any advice would as always be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By using `.value` you should get the current value from the `<select>`. Doesn't pick anything?

Comment: @Joel, I did a quick test on your live page and saw that the "desired value" from local storage was (in my test) `\nMeat and Meat Quality\n` but the actual text in the select dropdown is missing those newline characters. I'd guess the `sdd.options[i].text === desiredValue` test is failing accordingly. There's also a bug in the live page with `var x = document.getElementById(sdd)` (with `sdd` being an HTMLElement, not a string), but that's not in your original post, so I'm guessing it's something you've added since then.

Comment: @Thriggle That's really useful to know regarding the newline characters. I might run the `localStorage` variable through a `RegEx` treatment to strip those out (if they exist) so it is a full text match on the `<select>` drop down options. As you rightfully pointed out, the `sdd` code was added in after I asked this original question and I'm in the process of reverting back to the original code so the example is functional again.

Comment: That should work. You could also tweak your code on the course information page so it selects the text content from the `<h2>` element, instead of from the `<h2>`'s parent element. `capturedTitle = document.querySelector("#imageTopHeading h2").textContent`

Comment: Absolutely right. The `capturedTitle = document.querySelect‌​or("#imageTopHeading h2").textContent` approach worked, including in IE ( 9 >) and is a more elegant solution than running a RegEx. If you would like to formalise this information into an answer I will accept it, as the newline `\n` characters could certainly catch other people out in the future! Thanks once again.